# JS ArrayBuffer from XMLHttpRequest text

Tags: javascript, c, http, filereader, arraybuffer

I've been trying to use an `XMLHttpRequest` to get a binary file created from a C struct.

If I open the file in a hex editor, all characters are encoded as expected.

If I add the file to a static HTML page using `<input type='file' />` and then use `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`, I can see that the ArrayBuffer holds the same expected values.

But, when I try to send it over an `XMLHttpRequest`, and put its `responseText` into an `ArrayBuffer`, there are several characters that are replaced with the Unicode "replacement character".

If I use `FileReader.readAsText()` with the `<input type='file' />` test, I get the same character dropout that happens with `XMLHttpRequest.responseText`.

I have control over the file server, and I've tried adding a `Content-Type` header to the response (`application/octet-stream`?), but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

What am I missing here to ensure that the `XMLHttpRequest.responseText` has the correct data so the `ArrayBuffer` is created with the same values as the `FileReader` way?

Comment: What is the content type of the AJAX *request*?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'm not setting a type for the request - the server is pretty bare bones and I don't think it would ack any non-default request headers :)

Comment: Did you look at the request to make sure the ArrayBuffer's contents were sent as is? It's hard to debug without knowing who the culprit is. Can you confirm this is a client or server issue?

Comment: It appears to have been on the client. The server was indeed sending the correct content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, after hours of working on this, right after I rubber duck on SO I find the solution.

[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) has a `response` property - I shouldn't be using `responseText`.  Also, I can set the [responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType) property before I send the request to ensure it's returned in an ArrayBuffer.